# C# Windsor Castle with ASP.Net Web forms - How to Resolving Business Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I'm starting to use the Windsor Castle IoC container. The web app is ASP.Net Web forms, and there is a class library of business objects that I'm trying to add DI to.

I am initializing the Windsor Container in the Global.asax Application_Start method. I really will only want the container to be used in the Business Class library. The Class library doesn't know about the web application. It's in a different project.

What is the preferred way to initialize and resolve objects in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

i don't think you should use a DI container in your BL. this is the whole point with DI. object composition can be done in a variety of ways and this is determined in the composition root of your application. your composition root is not in your BL therefore the BL should have no reference to Castle Windsor. your composition root (the place where the objects are actually composed, where dependencies are actually resolved) is your web application project. it is there that you should decide how to compose your object graph: use Windsor, another container or poor man's DI.

also, creating the composition root in a web forms app is a little tricky. you can read more about this in 'Dependency injection in .net' by Mark Seemann p224-p230